# Rails: convert UTC DateTime to another time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, runtime

In Ruby/Rails, how do I convert a UTC DateTime to another time zone?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

```
time.in_time_zone(time_zone)
```

Example:

```
zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Central Time (US & Canada)")
Time.now.in_time_zone(zone)
```

or just

```
Time.now.in_time_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)")
```

You can find the names of the ActiveSupport time zones by doing:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:name)
# or for just US
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map(&:name)
```

Comment: In irb, when I try Time.now.in_time_zone('CST'), I get the error "undefined method 'in_time_zone'".  Are there rails classes that I need in order to get this to work?

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? Does it work if you do Time.zone.now.in_time_zone(...)?

Comment: To use this outside Rails, `require 'active_support/time'` first.

Comment: You can list all time zones by running `rake time:zones:all`. Also see `rake -D time`. Set the default time zone in `config/application.rb`.

Comment: @AdamEberlin In Rails you usually use ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone, not DateTime. All this code works on ruby DateTime objects as well as Time objects.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Thanks for the info. I was doing this in plain ruby, not in RAILS (for once), so perhaps they do differ in behavior. I'll remove my previous comment.

Comment: You can also get a list of all time zones from the [ActiveSupport::TimeZone documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) page.

Comment: For GMT use `in_time_zone('GMT')`. Easy!

Answer (score 10):

if `Time.zone` it's your desired time zone then you can use `@date.to_time.to_datetime`

```
> @date
=> Tue, 02 Sep 2014 23:59:59 +0000
> @date.class
=> DateTime
> @date.to_time
=> 2014-09-02 12:59:59 -1100
> @date.to_time.to_datetime
=> Tue, 02 Sep 2014 12:59:59 -1100
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Rails 5
`
Time.zone # => Europe/Paris
my_date  # => Wed, 29 Mar 2017 19:00:20 +0200
my_date.to_time # => "2017-03-29T17:00:20.000+00:00"
my_date.to_time.to_datetime # => Wed, 29 Mar 2017 17:00:20 +0000
`

Answer (score 5):

In plain ruby, with only `require 'date'`, use the `new_offset` method:

```
require 'date'

d=DateTime.parse('2000-01-01 12:00 +0200')
l=d.new_offset('-0700')
u=l.new_offset('UTC')
puts "#{u.strftime('%a %F %T %Z')} ❖ #{l.strftime('%a %F %T %Z')}"
```

Tested with ruby 2.3.7 that came standard on Mac OS X 10.13.

Answer (score 3):

Try ActiveSupport's [TimeWithZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) objects manipulated with TimeZone.  ActiveSupport also provides the in_time_zone method for converting a UTC time to a specified TimeZone time zone.  mckeed's answer shows the code.

Comment: What's the syntax for importing TimeWithZone into my class?  Or do I get it by default with Rails?

Comment: I believe you get it by default.  mckeed has the code you need, but you won't see it in irb.  You need to run it in Rails.

Comment: You're right - thanks, Fred - it does come with Rails by default.  I was grasping at straws, trying to get it working in irb.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case, if you are dealing with ActiveRecord object in Rails.

It might be a good idea to use `Time.use_zone` for a per request basis timezone that overrides the default timezone set in `config.time_zone`

More details I explain at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25055692/542995

Answer (score 0):

I'm using simple_form in Rails 4 and I just added the input field as

```
<%= f.input :time_zone, :as => :time_zone %>
```

with the migration

```
class AddTimeZoneColumnToTextmessage < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :textmessages, :time_zone, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how you convert DateTime objects