# Are the Date, Time, and DateTime classes necessary?

Tags: ruby

What is the purpose of having `Date` and `Time` classes when there is a `DateTime` class that can handle both?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`DateTime` is a subclass of `Date`, so whatever you can do with `Date` can be done with `DateTime`. But as tadman and steenslag point out, `DateTime` is slower. See steenslag's answer for how much slower it is.

With respect to `DateTime` vs, `Time`, I found something [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/146117#646897):

> Time is a wrapper around Unix-Epoch.
> Date (and DateTime) use rational and a "day zero" for storage. So Time is faster but the upper and lower bounds are tied to epoch time (which for 32bit epoch times is something around 1970-2040...while Date (and DateTime) have an almost infinite range but are terribly slow.

In short, `DateTime` is an all around superstar, and should be preferred in general, but if you want to optimize to the last bit, using `Time` can improve performance.

Comment: `Date` is also useful because it doesn't have any associated time-zone information which can make some calculations needlessly difficult.

Comment: @tadman But doesn't the value of date also depend on the time zone?

Comment: Date doesn't care about time-zones, it doesn't even know what they are. Converting Date to DateTime, or vice-versa, will use a time-zone, but you need to specify it either as a default setting, or as a deliberate request.

Comment: DateTime should NOT be preferred in general. Beware that you can't do any Time arithmetic with DateTime as it's really just a Date with added time-of-day attributes. It only deals in whole days: `DateTime.new(2012,12,31,0,0,0) + 1 == DateTime.new(2013,1,1)`

Comment: Isn't this answer outdated? Since Ruby 2, the Time uses 63 bits from epoch and can range pretty much any date. Further, DateTime does not cover leap seconds (differences from atom oscillations and earth's rotation), which ironically will be experienced today Tuesday, June 30, 2015.

Answer (score 43):

To summarize what the common ruby time classes are:

#### `Time`

This is the basic workhorse core ruby time class.

- Has date and time attributes (year, month, day, hour, min, sec, subsec)
- Based on floating-point second intervals from unix epoch (1970-01-01)
- Can handle negative times before unix epoch
- Can handle time arithmetic in units of seconds
- Natively works in either UTC or "local" (system time zone)

There are really 3 kinds of Time object when it comes to dealing with time zones, let's look at a summer time to show DST:

```
utc = Time.utc(2012,6,1) # => 2012-12-21 00:00:00 UTC
utc.zone       # => "UTC"
utc.dst?       # => false
utc.utc?       # => true
utc.utc_offset # => 0

local = Time.local(2012,6,1) # => 2012-06-01 00:00:00 -0700
local.zone       # => "PDT"
local.dst?       # => true
local.utc?       # => false
local.utc_offset # => -25200

nonlocal = Time.new(2012,6,1,0,0,0, "-07:00") # => 2012-06-01 00:00:00 -0700
nonlocal.zone       # => nil
nonlocal.dst?       # => false
nonlocal.utc?       # => false
nonlocal.utc_offset # => -25200
```

The last 2 look similar, but beware: **you should not do arithmetic with a non-local Time**. This is simply a time with a UTC offset and no zone, so it doesn't know the rules of DST. Adding time over the DST boundary will not change the offset and the resulting time-of-day will be wrong.

#### `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`

This one is worth mentioning here since it's what you use in Rails. Same as Time, plus:

- Can handle any time zone
- Respects DST
- Can convert times between zones

I generally always reach for this when ActiveSupport is available as it takes care of all the time zone pitfalls.

#### `Date`

- Has date attributes only (year, month, day)
- Based on integer whole-day intervals from an arbitrary "day zero" (-4712-01-01)
- Can handle date arithmetic in units of whole days
- Can convert between dates in the ancient Julian calendar to modern Gregorian

Date is more useful than Time whenever you deal in whole days: no time zones to worry about! (I'm surprised this doesn't deal with the modern Persian calendar since it knows about the obsolete Julian calendar from centuries ago.)

#### `DateTime`

- Has date and time attributes (year, month, day, hour, min, sec)
- Based on fractions of whole-day intervals from an arbitrary "day zero" (-4712-01-01)
- Can handle date arithmetic in units of whole days or fractions

Personally, I *never* have reason to use this: it's slow, it handles time without considering time zones, and it has an inconsistent interface. I find it leads to confusion whenever you assume you have a Time-like object, but it actually **behaves like a Date** instead:

```
Time.new(2012, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0) + 1 == Time.new(2012, 12, 31, 0, 0, 1)
DateTime.new(2012, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0) + 1 == DateTime.new(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

Further, it has a meaningless "zone" attribute (note how non-local Time objects warn you that `zone == nil`), and you can't know anything else about it before turning it into a Time first:

```
dt = DateTime.new(2012,12,6, 1, 0, 0, "-07:00")
dt.zone # => "-07:00"
dt.utc? # => NoMethodError: undefined method `utc?'
dt.dst? # => NoMethodError: undefined method `dst?'
dt.utc_offset # => NoMethodError: undefined method `utc_offset'
```

Dealing with microseconds to check for rounding is also a little strange. You would think that because it doesn't have a `usec` attribute that it only deals in whole numbers, but you'd be wrong:

```
DateTime.now.usec # => NoMethodError: undefined method `usec'
DateTime.now.to_time.usec => 629399
```

In short, unless you're dealing with astronomical events in the ancient past and need to convert the Julian date (with time of day) to a modern calendar, please don't use DateTime. If anyone has an actual use case for this class, I'd love to read your comments.

Comment: I just found a use for `DateTime` today... a calendar/scheduling application which allows the user to create recurring appointments, which should appear at the chosen time of day *even when crossing DST boundaries*. This is most simply accomplished by using a class which doesn't know anything about DST.

Comment: @AlexD interesting: that makes sense, since DateTime's time is treated almost like a literal attribute or "fractional part" of the day. Are you aware of the ice_cube gem by the way? I'm currently thinking of stripping DateTime support out of it, but if you have other thoughts on this please add input on https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube/issues/114

Comment: @AlexD I'd just like to point out that you can do the same thing with a "non-local" Time, e.g. `Time.new(,,,,,,"-08:00")` which gives a UTC offset but ignores DST. In either case you have to beware that the UTC offset will be wrong half the year, so any comparisons with an actual time (like "now") might be wrong.

Comment: I'm doing all calculations in UTC, and then converting to the user's timezone "at the last minute" -- just before displaying results. So I think comparisons with "now" won't be a problem. Thanks for the point about `Time.new`... I never knew that.

Comment: Don't use DateTime.  Also, I gave a lightning talk at rubyconf 2012 on timezones and went to look at my notes and saw "TODO: Date vs. Time vs. DateTime".  https://gist.github.com/3668333 https://github.com/bf4/Notes/blob/master/talks_mine/time-lightning-rubyconf2012.pdf?raw=true http://vimeo.com/53892354

Comment: I think I found a valid reason to use DateTime. DateTime seems to be the only one that supports `strptime`.

Comment: @PauloCasaretto If you `require 'time'` from stdlib then it adds `Time#strptime` to the core Time class. (Not sure why it is like that.)

Comment: Thanks to Zachary Scott there's now an answer in Ruby source with a nice example https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/45458752d3f54ac81661d93aa55b8b5805f78138#diff-3991f2801546530eb23774963a10fa94R9476 (original gist https://gist.github.com/pixeltrix/e2298822dd89d854444b ) h/t http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2015/6/6/this-week-in-rails-datetime-vs-time-summer-student-projects-and-more/

Comment: The Julian calendar is not as old in some countries. For example, the Julian calendar was used into WWI in Russia (it is part of what makes the Russian revolution so confusing) and in Greece until the 1920's (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_of_the_Gregorian_calendar).

Answer (score 28):

I know there is an accepted answer but I have something to add. The Date class is a heavyweight, academic strength class. It can handle all sorts of RFC's, parse the strangest things and converts julian dates from thousand years ago to gregorian with the reform date of choice. The Time class is lightweight and it does not know of any of this stuff. It's cheaper and that shows up in a benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'date'

Benchmark.bm(10) do |x|
  x.report('date'){100000.times{Date.today} }
  x.report('datetime'){100000.times{DateTime.now} }
  x.report('time'){100000.times{Time.now} }
end
```

Result:

```
                user     system      total        real
date        1.250000   0.270000   1.520000 (  1.799531)
datetime    6.660000   0.360000   7.020000 (  7.690016)
time        0.140000   0.030000   0.170000 (  0.200738)
```

(Ruby 1.9.2)

Comment: There's no difference between date and datetime in 2.0

Answer (score 4):

Another way of thinking of this is that `Date` and `DateTime` model time in terms of clocks and calendars, which is useful for describing times to users, and scheduling events. Having a `Date` without a time is nice for when you don't care about the time, and you don't want to think about time zones.

`Time` models time as a continuum, and is a wrapper around the Unix timestamp, which is just an integer. This is useful for all manner of internal applications where the computer doesn't care much whether a calendar boundary has been crossed, but just how many seconds (or milliseconds) have elapsed.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Date handles only the date for something, I.E., March 31, 1989. But it does not handle Time, for example, 12:30 PM.
DateTime, can handle both, March 31, 1989 12:30 PM EST.

Sometimes you don't need all parts of the DateTime. For example, you wanted to know when the use signed up for you website, Date would be useful here, because the time is eventually irrelevant.

In some cases you might want just the time. For example, if it's lunch time, you may want to tell the user your office is closed. At this point, the Data is irrelevant.

However, in most cases DateTime is used, because it can be used as either date, time, or both.

Comment: Yes, I know this. Quite obvious. My question is why have separate classes for Date and Time? Why not have _just_ DateTime? You could, for example, parse a string containing "7:30 PM EST" and know for sure that would be a time, so create an instance of DateTime with only the Time functionality.

Comment: You mention that in most cases DateTime is used. So why clutter the stdlib with unnecessary classes?

Comment: A long can work as an integer also, but you wouldn't want to change all your ints to longs because it wastes space and isn't the right tool for the job. A float can also work, but math involve it takes longer.

Comment: Ruby isn't statically typed like that (Unless you're using ffi or ruby-inline, of coarse.)

Comment: The answer is still the same. You should use the best tool for the job. Take for example vice grips, they can do anything, but they're hardly ever the best tool for the job.

Comment: Well, that's kind of the gist of my question. Why would we create/use other "tools (Date and Time) if there already is one that could be the best (DateTime)?

Comment: Because DateTime isn't the best, for the examples I described in my answer. It can be used for most operations, just like vice grips, but sometimes there are better tools.

Comment: @Malfist: Been thinking about it some more. You said that changing all ints to longs in a C++ program would waste space, saying that the Date class should be used over a DateTime class if we're only ever gonna use it for dates. That does make sense in theory, but if the Time class can parse "7:30 PM", and the Date class can parse "5/9/11".. then why couldn't the DateTime class parse the strings and return an instance of itself with only the functionality it needs for what it parsed. For example if I parse "7:30 PM" with DateTime, then the instance it returns would act like an instance of Time.

Comment: But DateTime will assume you mean today, so you will have Today's Date, 7:30 PM. If you checked that datetime tomorrow, it'll be yesterday's date, 7:30 PM. Time will always be 7:30 PM.
DateTime doesn't need to figure out the functionality you want, because it wouldn't know, and there are already other classes for that. If you're using DateTime, you are saying you need both the date and the time. If you only need the time, then use Time.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the question. I know the current functionality of Date, Time, and DateTime. I dont want to know "Is DateTime the best tool for the job?", but rather "Why DateTime isn't the best tool for the job?" in the sense that all three classes should be rolled into one.

Comment: Time is not a TimeOfDay class. It is a timestamp. See my answer.

Comment: This answer is misleading. Time includes date information; there is no reason to use DateTime just to "add" date. If you want just "time of day" absent the date, there is a separate "tod" gem for that.