# Why does Ruby's stdlib have a DateTime class?

Tags: ruby, datetime

A little while ago I dug deep into the [differences between Ruby's time-like classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941613/are-the-date-time-and-datetime-classes-necessary/14007547#14007547). After asking around, I've come to the conclusion that there is **no good reason to use DateTime**, ever.

This question is essentially the inverse of the one asked above:

Why was `DateTime` originally added to the stdlib when Date and Time can do everything just fine, and better? Who actually uses DateTime (and for what) such that it continues to have a place in stdlib?

Answer (score 1):

DateTime was popularized as a Rails thing where it was created to wrap around equivalent `DATETIME` columns in the database. These columns were much more flexible than `Time` in terms of date ranges so a new type was required to capture all possible values. In Ruby 1.8.6 and early versions of 1.8.7 times are limited to the standard 1901-2038 range, represented internally as an unsigned long (32-bit) number.

Now the differences are mostly minor, though within Rails most of the time calculation methods are DateTime only.

I really wouldn't worry about which of DateTime or Time you use unless you have an especially good reason to prefer one over the other. If you're getting DateTime objects from Rails, go with the flow and use those. If you're building your own Ruby application, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: This is wrong. Rails uses `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. Yes, time zone handling wasn't always there, but `DateTime` predates Rails. See [https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/dc9cd6a8c22ad04baa7498fd0cbc5d519ed73be0/lib/date.rb#L436]. Also there are serious deficiencies in DateTime if you look into it.

Comment: It's possible that historically you may have a point about wider date ranges with `DateTime`, but even in 1.8.7 (the only "old" ruby I have installed right now), I can create `Time.utc(-2500, 12, 31, 12, 34, 56)` just fine: maybe a question of 64-bit OS?

Comment: I'm not sure when Time was patched to account for a much wider range, but the original version was strictly 32-bit signed and would error out for values outside 1901 through 2038. This could be a fix from Ruby 1.9 that's been back-ported into the 1.8.7 series. Testing in 1.8.6 yields "RangeError: bignum too big to convert into `long'".

Comment: Re: "within Rails most of the calculation methods are DateTime", I see: [deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb#L29), [avoided](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb#L250), and even ActiveSupport's `DateTime#advance` [internally uses Date](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb#L68). (I have no love for DateTime either.)

Comment: I'll probably have to dig into the internals of Date, DateTime, TimeWithZone, and Time to figure out where things stand now in Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3. Seems like a lot of things have changed. I bet it's still a train-wreck in there, though, as time and dates are one of those things that are fuzzy at best.