# Save DateTime to Database: Timezone Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have set

```
config.time_zone = 'Berlin'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

in "application.rb" and restartet WEBrick Webserver an "remigrated" (rake db:drop; rake db:migrate) my database.

If I check Entries in my Database, everything is fine and the "created_at" is correctly saved in my Localtimezone:

```
sqlite> select created_at from docversions;
2011-08-22 23:27:51.138723
sqlite>
```

But in this case, this "Local Timezone" doesnt work:

(creat.html.erb)

```
<%= form_for :token, :url => {:action => "save_token"}, :docversion_id => params[:id] do |f| %>
<%= f.datetime_select :validuntil, :order => [:day, :month, :year, :hour, :minute], :default => 3.days.from_now,  %>
<%= f.submit %>
```

(tokenadmin_controller.rb)

```
class TokenadminController < ApplicationController
  def save_token
    @token = Token.new
    civildate = DateTime.civil(params[:token]["validuntil(1i)"].to_i,
                               params[:token]["validuntil(2i)"].to_i,
                               params[:token]["validuntil(3i)"].to_i,
                               params[:token]["validuntil(4i)"].to_i,
                               params[:token]["validuntil(5i)"].to_i)
    @token.validuntil = civildate
    if @token.save
      flash[:notice] = "Token created."
      redirect_to :controller => :tokenadmin, :action => :admin
    else
      flash[:error] = "Token could not be saved!"
      redirect_to :controller => "index"
    end 
  end 
end
```

It seems that it would be saved as UTC:

```
sqlite> select validuntil, created_at from tokens;
2011-08-22 01:44:00.000000|2011-08-22 23:44:20.640434
sqlite>
```

As you can see, created_at is correctly saved as Localtime, but validuntil is saved +2h (but i have selected the same time as create_at ;-)). I think its +2h because were in a timezone wich is UTC+1 and in DST UTC+2. And were in DST at the moment.

Is that a bug, or did I do something wrong?

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE AFTER POST FROM "BaronVonBraun":**

Thanks! Its working now.
Databasefield is still "timestamp":

```
t.timestamp :validuntil
```

Controller code, wich is use to create a Time-field:

Before:

```
civildate = DateTime.civil(params[:token]["validuntil(1i)"].to_i,
                           params[:token]["validuntil(2i)"].to_i,
                           params[:token]["validuntil(3i)"].to_i,
                           params[:token]["validuntil(4i)"].to_i,
                           params[:token]["validuntil(5i)"].to_i)
```

After:

```
civildate = Time.parse("#{params[:token]["validuntil(1i)"].to_s}-#{params[:token]["validuntil(2i)"].to_s}-#{params[:token]["validuntil(3i)"].to_s} #{params[:token]["validuntil(4i)"].to_s}:#{params[:token]["validuntil(5i)"].to_s}")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime` objects are in GMT/UTC (+0000 offset) by default.

If you want to store your local timezone along with your date object, I'd suggest using `Time` instead of `DateTime`, which should use the timezone you've set in your Rails config.

If you need to continue using `DateTime`, here is an answer to another question: [How do I alter the timezone of a DateTime in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467781/how-do-i-alter-the-timezone-of-a-datetime-in-ruby/4492465#4492465).  However, in that solution, it sets the timezone to a hard offset, meaning it wouldn't handle going in and out of DST.