# DateTime.new with timezone (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone

DateTime.new takes a timezone parameter as the 7th argument as an integer offset.

```
DateTime.new(2001,2,3,4,5,6,'-7')
```

However, since I don't easily know whether a given time falls in Daylight or Standard, I would rather do something like:

```
DateTime.new(2001,2,3,4,5,6,'Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
```

Please advise

Comment: you'll have to write a wrapper and list all the offsets.

Comment: See also the section on Rails at the bottom of [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Rails your best bet is:

```
cur_zone = Time.zone
begin
  Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
  datetime = Time.zone.local(2001, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
ensure
  Time.zone = cur_zone
end
```

Or if you've already set `Time.zone` when you authenticate your uses, or in your `application.rb` config file then you can just use the `Time.zone.local` line by itself.

Comment: I went with the Rails best bet.  I'm not certain how the second suggestion solves the Standard -vs- Daylight issue.  Thanks!!

Comment: The second approach would just return the *standard* offset, which might not be the correct offset for the date in question.  The first approach looks better.

Comment: I removed the second part from the answer.  I hope @nzifnab doesn't mind.

Comment: Ahh good point about DST and such.  I was just pointing out a way to get the offset value -- but realistically you shouldn't need to. I'm fine with the edit, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Idea found in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41584881/3837660

In e.g. `Rails 5.2.3`

```rb
DateTime.included_modules.third
# => DateAndTime::Zones
```

which has `#in_time_zone`.
(https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Zones.html)

Allowing you to do the following:

```rb
#########################################
# Summer example
#
DateTime.new.in_time_zone(
  'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
).change(
  year: 2017,
  month: 7,
  day: 31,
  hour: 7,
  min: 59,
  sec: 23
)
#
# => Mon, 31 Jul 2017 07:59:23 EDT -04:00
#
#########################################

#########################################
# Winter example
DateTime.new.in_time_zone(
  'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
).change(
  year: 2017,
  month: 12,
  day: 31,
  hour: 7,
  min: 59,
  sec: 23
)
#
# => Sun, 31 Dec 2017 07:59:23 EST -05:00
#
#########################################
```

Note that `DateTime#change` is also an addition from Rails.
See, e.g., https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-change for details.

Comment: excellent up to date answer that finally provides a sane way to handle ruby's goofy timezones