# Convert UTC Time to PST Time Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a time in the format `2020-03-15 02:00:00 UTC`, and I was curious how in Ruby I could convert this into something readable and in PST time, such as `March 15th, 2020 7:00:00 PM PST`? Preferably without any gems in plain Ruby.

Comment: Just a heads up: *PDT* is -7, PST is -8

Comment: Ah got it, I wasn't paying too much to the exact conversion in my post just using it as an example for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DateTime.strptime(string, format) to parse the utc string into a datetime object and then use strftime(format) to format it how you want. Something like:

```
date = DateTime.strptime("2020-03-15 02:00:00 UTC", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC")
formatted_date = date.strftime("...")
```

https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

Comment: Thanks! This parses it really well, but now that I have `formatted_date`, how can I convert that from the UTC time that it is in into PST?

Comment: Never done that, but you could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467781/how-do-i-alter-the-timezone-of-a-datetime-in-ruby