# How to deal with UTC times and Rails/ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone, ruby-on-rails-3.2, utc

I'm using Rails 3.2.8. When I generate a scaffold with a time field or datetime field. The HTML form field gets pre-populated with the current date/time in UTC. Great that it's pre-populated with the current date/time, but because it's in UTC, we have to change the time back 7 hours every time (which will sometimes require setting the day back 1 also, possibly month and year too). And then it seems the UTC time gets stored in the database, so I'll have issues displaying/editing it as well if I recorded it in our local time.

I looked at the [Ruby documentation for the form helpers to deal with local time](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_select) better, but I don't see anything relevant.

What's the best way to deal with editing and displaying dates and times in Rails?

***UPDATE***: To clarify, I like the idea that UTC time is stored in the database. I just want the `time_select` and `datetime_select` form helpers to edit the times in the user's local timezone. And, of course, I want to easily display the time in the user's local timezone.

Comment: How about setting the default timezone in `config/application.rb` instead? That way, such issues won't arrive at first place.
`config.time_zone = "foo_place"`

Comment: The time zone might be different for different users.

Comment: @at. did you find an answer? i'm having the same issue. The user-specific timezone is set in the application controller, so I can display date just fine. 

I've got a column that is type 'time' in the migration. I'm using a time_select helper in the view. However, the time_select seems to ignore thee user-timezone preference. It just displays in the zone as it's stored in the DB not the user-timezone. Also, when the form is saved, it's interpreted as UTC not the user-timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the time zone to display on a per-user basis somewhere in a `before/around_filter`. This has to be done like:

```
Time.zone = "Kyiv"
```

An example can be found in its API: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-zone-3D.

Run the `rake time:zones:all` to see all of them.

All the conversions has to be handled for you behind the scene.

Comment: That definitely helped, but I'm more confused now about how Rails deals with date/times and timezones. So I did a `Time.zone="Pacific Time (US & Canada)"` in the `new` method of a scaffold. Worked brilliantly for my `datetime` field. Was able to edit/create/display it in local time and it saved it in the database in UTC time. I just can't set the timezone for the update/create methods of the controller. However, my `time` fields completely disregard the `Time.zone` setting. It's **always** UTC time for everything. I guess I can't use `time` fields and `time_select` for zone-sensitive things?

Comment: I miswrote the above. I have to put `Time.zone="Pacific Time (US & Canada)"` at the beginning of all methods in the scaffold (or of course use a filter). But the issue still remains for `time` fields and `time_select` form helpers, they disregard the `Time.zone`.

Comment: @at. *So I did a `Time.zone="Pacific Time (US & Canada)"` in the new method of a scaffold* - but you have to do it in a filter, to ensure it's called for every action.

Comment: you could just put that `Time.zone` code at the top of every method as I described. I also mentioned "(or of course use a filter)".

Comment: @at. I'm little confused: you're sometimes saying about `time`, about `datetime` and `date`. What exactly type of field do you have?

Comment: I have multiple fields. Some are `datetime` and some are `time`. The `datetime`s now work great thanks to your help, but the `time` fields don't deal with timezones well at all.

Comment: I ended up simply migrating my time fields to datetime fields. Annoying, but couldn't find any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This has helped me in the past. You can do things like:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)")
```

See [Rails: convert UTC DateTime to another time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695837/rails-convert-utc-datetime-to-another-time-zone)

Comment: That's great for displaying the right time. But creating/editing the time with the `datetime_select` and `time_select` form helpers is another story.